# compatibility mode causes css problems

Tags: css, compatibility-mode

Good day, all,

I am afraid I cannot share a working URL or sample code for this one; I'm working on a proprietary site for a client. I am also unable to replicate in an environment in which I build sample code from the ground up. Rather, I'm being forced to use code supplied by my client and have to tweak it to make it work. Throwing it all out and starting over is not an option and since I didn't build it, initially, I've no idea why certain things are coded the way they are.

Believe me:  I want to do this from scratch ... this is real spaghetti-code.

What I would like to know is if anyone here has heard of this general problem and if there are any approaches I could use to find fixes and work-arounds.

PROBLEM:  The site displays just fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE8, and IE9. When in IE8 or IE9, if I enter "Compatibility Mode", the layout shifts and becomes slightly skewed and broken. Z-indexes don't seem to work properly, background image positioning seems off, and some heights seem broken.

QUESTION:  Has anyone heard of this or found ways to address/target CSS interpretation bugs that only appear in "Compatibility Mode"?

Yours,
Dave

Comment: I'm afraid there's no "general problem"when it comes to IE. IE is the general problem. Without code we can't really help you.

Comment: Sorry cannot help you without more info (simple sample code with the error)

Comment: I am using Transitional, Diodeus.

Comment: I am also working on a site that works fine in modern browsers but does not work on IE9 or earlier.  If I turn on the compatibility mode on IE11 I can see the behaviour.  At first I thought changing CSS would work.  Not so.  Look at the development tools console (F12) differences between IE11 and compatibility view.  There might be some objects or properties undefined or null reference.  Tackle these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've seen this at msdn - might be helpful:
[Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Scott:  thank you for the link. It appears that the issue is that my understanding of "Compatibility Mode" was a bit off. If I'm understanding this correctly, IE8 and IE9 both display with CSS display bugs common to IE7 if "Compatibility Mode" is turned on.

Essentially, the issue was a variety of nested items, some using position:relative and some using absolute.